# Can summoned creatures take items back with them?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, summoning

If you summon a creature and give it any item then dismiss it, does the item go with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It would require a DM ruling.

There are no specific mention of rules that specifically address that concern. But one should consider the following:

**Paladin's Special Mount**

> Each time the mount is called, it appears in full health, regardless of any damage it may have taken previously. **The mount also appears wearing or carrying any gear it had when it was last dismissed.** Calling a mount is a [conjuration (calling)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#calling) effect. Should the paladin’s mount die, it immediately disappears, leaving behind any equipment it was carrying.

The main reason a Paladin's Mount is a conjuration (calling), rather than [conjuration (summoning)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#summoning), is due to [dispel](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) circumstances. It wouldn't be fun for the [paladin](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm) if someone simply dispelled his [mount](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm#specialMount) from underneath him (although some may find that hilarious).

Also consider the aspect of [conjuration (teleportation).](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#teleportation) For example, the [teleportation spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) states:

> You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load.

Since extraplanar travel isn't allowed with teleportation explicitly, lets look at [Lesser Planar Ally](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planarAllyLesser.htm):

> A task taking up to 1 minute per caster level requires a payment of 100 gp per HD of the creature called.
>
> At the end of its task, or when the duration bargained for expires, the creature returns to its home plane (after reporting back to you, if appropriate and possible).

Depending on the amount of hit dice, that could be a considerable amount of gold - and weight.

### Opinion

I would say Conjuration (Summoning), No; Conjuration (Calling), Yes. And that would make perfect sense. Your DM would be the final arbiter. But imagine the implications if he allowed someone to be grabbed and sucked into whatever plane the creature was summoned from...

Then again, it could be one heck of an adventure hook:

[image: Freddy Krueger]

Comment: Is your opinion of no for summoning based around the text for calling specifies (and summoning doesn't) or is there something more to it?  You gave a bunch of reasons I can agree why calling may be yes, but I am not sure why you believe summoning would be no.

Comment: Summoning (Calling) with Lesser Planar Ally requires an amount of gold. Gold is a tangible object that will be going with the creature when it travels. Summoning (Calling) with a Paladin's Mount literally states it has material when it comes and goes. There is no mention at all with any Conjuration (Summoning) that material can be transferred during transport. It could be to do that Summoning is simply too temporary compared to calling to allow that sort of transfer.

Answer (score 7):

The items remain per the [Main FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111194213/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a) (p91).

> **What happens to a summoned monster’s equipment when it dies or the spell ends? What if it’s not carrying the equipment any more? What if
> it’s carrying something new?** When a summoned creature goes away, so
> does everything it came with. If it’s holding or wearing something it
> didn’t appear with, that item drops to the ground in the creature’s
> space after it disappears.

The only arguement (besides Main FAQ haters;)) I can see here is if you believe "spell ending" and dismissing the spell are different but I believe they are the same.

Answer (score 6):

### No,  but a *[Called](http://dndsrd.net/magicSchools.html#calling)* creature can

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (37) has a say in this matter:

> **Improving Creatures:** [...] The trick is, a summoned creature can’t take things back home with it. When a summoned creature disappears, it leaves all the things that it gained while on the Material Plane.

Although the sidebar's main topic is about a variant rule (summoning non-random creatures), the quote is referring to the general case.
However, the rest of the paragraph points out how a *Conjuration (Calling)* effect allows the called creature to keep the given items; a rule that finds support in various descriptions of the *Player's Handbook* (see [Ruut's comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63767/can-summoned-creatures-take-items-back-with-them#comment137344_63774)).