# What happens to creatures Swallowed Whole by a summoned creature when that creature is dismissed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, summoning

I am a conjurer and I have a particularly nefarious idea. Granted there are monsters I can summon with the "Swallow Whole (Ex)" ability, and I then dismiss my summon after the summoned creature has swallowed the desired target(s).

What happens to the unfortunate souls that have been eaten by the creature?

Will they be left behind, or be taken with the creature to its native plane?

- The creatures swallowed are still alive at the moment of dismissal.
- Does it matter if the creature is instead dispelled or banished?

Comment: Related, maybe dupe, if you extrapolate that what applies to carried objects applies to carried creatures: [Can summoned creatures take items back with them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63767/28402)

Comment: @Carcer: Definitely not a duplicate, albeit related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It stays

As this [Answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63857/51979) states from the question [Can summoned creatures take items back with them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63767/can-summoned-creatures-take-items-back-with-them)

The FAQ answers it (p.91)

> **What happens to a summoned monster’s equipment when it dies or the
> spell ends? What if it’s not carrying the equipment any more? What if
> it’s carrying something new?**
> When a summoned creature goes away, so
> does everything it came with. If it’s holding or wearing something it
> didn’t appear with, that item drops to the ground in the creature’s
> space after it disappears.

If we only consider summoned monsters with a temporary duration spell, I believe the same thing would happen if the creature dies, the spell ends,if you *dismiss the spell*,use *dismissal*,*banishment* or even *dispel magic* on them.

However for a creature that is on the material plane (that wasn't summoned with a temporary spell) targeted with the spells *Banishment* or *Dismissal* it seems like there is no official ruling about it, I guess all their equipments goes with them (I don't know about newly acquired equipment that could be another question on its own) but since only extraplanar creatures can be targeted they would not bring the other creature with them, unless it is also another extraplanar creature (and that you also would try to target with Banishment).

But I think you can't target the swallowed creature though because it would benefit from *total cover* and *total concealment* as well.

Magic works in mysterious ways... it does not always make sense...

Comment: Can someone help on dispel for a summon and total cover and concealment? and if dismissal or banishment has a rule about equipment. could not find anything in the FAQ.

Comment: And newly acquired equipment for the extraplanar creatures on our plan, but I guess that could be an entirely different question.

Comment: A summon can be targeted by a targeted dispel and then be resolved like any other dispel magic spell targeting a spell effect. That much I know for certain since I've employed that tactic before. Though there are also ways a conjure can heighten the spellcaster check needed to achieve a dispel magic on a summoned creature, thus making it very hard to dispel and making options like banishment a more reliabpe way of dealing with summons.

Comment: When PCs are on a plane they aren't native to, they gain the subtype [extraplanar](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#extraplanar) which, in turn, allows PCs to be targets of [*banishment*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#banishment) and [*dismissal*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dismissal) spells! If that happens and the DM rules that the PCs appear on their native planes, like, naked or even just without the treasure they acquired while planehopping, I'm pretty sure the DM's car will be vandalized.

Comment: Yes but you can t target a swallowed creature anyways so it will not work IMO but a DM could rule it works. They will be sent to different planes though which could save the PC too. Funny comment xD